React native IOS - FirebaseCoreInternal.modulemap not found
I am trying to build a React Native ios app on Xcode and I keep getting the below error /User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-dokbeeueevdjhqfdmixtepepfamp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/appname.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appname.build/DerivedSources/appname.c module map file
/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-dokbeeueevdjhqfdmixtepepfamp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCoreInternal/FirebaseCoreInternal.modulemap' not found
The error reference this appname_vers.c file - /User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-dokbeeueevdjhqfdmixtepepfamp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/appname.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appname.build/DerivedSources/appname_vers.c
 extern const unsigned char appnamEVersionString[];
 extern const double appnameVersionNumber;

 const unsigned char appnameVersionString[] __attribute__ ((used)) = 
       "@(#)PROGRAM:appname  PROJECT:appname-1" "\n";
 const double appnameVersionNumber __attribute__ ((used)) = (double)1.;

My react-native info is:
System:
   OS: macOS 14.4.1
   CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Max
   Memory: 75.52 MB / 32.00 GB
   Shell:
     version: "5.9"
     path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 20.11.0
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/node
  Yarn:
    version: 1.22.22
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/yarn
  npm:
    version: 10.2.4
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2024.01.22.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
     version: 1.15.2
    path: /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 23.4
      - iOS 17.4
      - macOS 14.4
      - tvOS 17.4
      - visionOS 1.1
      - watchOS 10.4
   Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
   Android Studio: 2023.1 AI-231.9392.1.2311.11330709
   Xcode:
      version: 15.3/15E204a
      path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
 Languages:
      Java:
         version: 21.0.2
         path: /usr/bin/javac
     Ruby:
        version: 2.6.10
        path: /usr/bin/ruby
 npmPackages:
     @react-native-community/cli": Not Found
     react:
       installed: 18.2.0
       wanted: 18.2.0
     react-native:
       installed: 0.73.7
        wanted: 0.73.7
    react-native-macos: Not Found
     npmGlobalPackages:
     "*react-native*": Not Found
  Android:
     hermesEnabled: true
      newArchEnabled: false
  iOS:
      hermesEnabled: true
      newArchEnabled: false

